# Using ggrepel with single plot point/adding line between label and point

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, ggrepel

Ok so I have a data set with 2 variables X and Y, and an ID variable. I've created a full plot using this code:

```
ggplot(data = X_Y) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y))+
  geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y, label = ID))+
  xlim(0,100)+
  ylim(0,100)
```

This produces a plot like this:
[image]

I now wish to create a number of separate plots only showing a single data point at a time with their label.

Now I can use just geom_label without repel and nudge the label to get this:
[image]

While this plot is ok, I was wondering if there was any way to keep the lines connecting labels to points like how ggrepel does...

**EDIT**

From the first suggestion, when I try use repel with only one case selected I get the following plot:

```
ggplot(data = X_Y) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = X[4], y = Y[4]))+
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = X[4], y = Y[4]), 
                   label = "You are here",
                   min.segment.length = unit(0, 'lines'),
                   nudge_y = 6)+
  labs(x = "X",y = "Y",title = "mytitle")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))
```

[image]

**RESOLVED**

Figured it out! I need to specify my data in ggplot() to only be the X and Y variables and limit to the row of interest.

Like this:

```
ggplot(data = X_Y[4,c(3,4)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = X, y = Y))+
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = X, y = Y), 
                   label = "You are here",
                   min.segment.length = unit(0, 'lines'),
                   nudge_y = 6)+
  labs(x = "X",y = "Y",title = "mytitle")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can of course still use `geom_label_repel`, even with a single point. To be sure a segment is drawn adjust the `min.segment.length` arg. This arg sets the minimum distance from the point to the label to draw a segment, setting it to `unit(0, 'lines')` ensures every segment is drawn:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(data.frame(x = 2, y = 3)) +
    geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
    geom_label_repel(aes(x, y), 
                     label = 'You are here', 
                     min.segment.length = unit(0, 'lines'), 
                     nudge_y = .2) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse!

I tried doing that but I get a weird graph, it looks like it's mapping labels for the total N of the dataset, but on that single point....I've edited my question above to showcase....

Comment: Figured it out! I need to specify my data in ggplot() to only be the X and Y variables and limit to the row of interest. Then it flows :)